# How do I capture a returned value from a stored procedure using windows command script?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, command-line, cmd

I am writing a command script that calls a stored procedure. That stored procedure returns a value that I need later in the script. Is there any way for me to capture that value into a variable of some sort?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In windows CMD shell, this can be done with a FOR loop on a sqlcmd call.  Usually only if the query returns 1 record.

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('sqlcmd <query paramters>') DO SET MYCMDVARIABLE=%%A
```

It can be configured for multiple columns, but will always return values from the last row in the SQL return set.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to call a stored procedure and retrieve its return value. The code creates a temporary stored procedure that takes two input parameters and returns their sum via the return value.  If your stored procedure executes queries, make sure you're processing all available results via sqlsrv_next_result before trying to access the return value.

I hope this information can help you..

Code is below:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('.\SQLExpress', array('Database'=>'Northwind'));

$sql = "CREATE PROCEDURE #ReturnParam (@p1 int, @p2 int) AS
        RETURN @p1 + @p2";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$sql = '{? = CALL #ReturnParam(?, ?)}';
$returnVariable = -1;
$inputVariable1 = 18;
$inputVariable2 = 24;

$params = array(array($returnVariable, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
                array($inputVariable1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($inputVariable2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

echo "Return value: ".$returnVariable;
```

Comment: Can you give an example where you're calling an existing stored procedure? I'm using osql to execute it.

Comment: Also, is this PHP? I'm using windows shell, so I'm not sure PHP would help me.

Comment: I'm working with straight scripting from the command shell, not any higher programming languages.

Comment: This code appears to be PowerShell (.ps1), not batch or command (.bat or .cmd).

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with SQL 2005 and above, try using **sqlcmd** instead.

Check out all the goodies it provides that you can use with scripting:
[MSDN Page for sqlcmd command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)